# using model classes with association for serialization and deserialization with jackson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have three classes with associations as follows:

**Process.java**

```
      @Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)
public class Process  {

    private UUID processId;

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<UnitType> units = new ArrayList<>();

    private String furtherComment;

    private List<AnsweredQuestionnaire> answeredQuestionnaires = new ArrayList<>()


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Process)) return false;
        Process process = (Process) o;
        return getProcessId().equals(process.getProcessId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getProcessId());
    }
}
```

**AnsweredQuestionnaire.java**

```
    @Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnsweredQuestionnaire {

    private UUID answeredQuestionnaireId;


    private Questionnaire questionnaire;

    private Process process;

    public void addProcessToAnsweredQuestionnaire(Process process){
        //remove old association
        if(this.process != null){
            this.process.getAnsweredQuestionnaires().remove(this);
        }
        this.process = process;

        //add new association
        if(process != null){
            this.process.getAnsweredQuestionnaires().add(this);
        }
    } 
}
```

**User.java**

```
 @Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private UUID userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addProcessToUser(Process process){
        this.processes.add(process);
        process.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProcessFromUser(Process process){
        this.processes.remove(process);
        process.getUsers().remove(this);
    }

}
```

I have to use these classes for serialization and deserialization using objectMapper. I dont know the proper way to use the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation. Could someone please suggest me how to implement this. With the work done above I get circular dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonBackReference (on the List property) and @JsonManagedReference (on the object property) annotations for avoid the circular reference on serialization.

Comment: Using these two annotation does not solve the issue, already tried. I got error like : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back reference property found from type

Comment: I must implement bidirectional dependency to access one entity from another.

Comment: When you have more than one reference to the same class, set name or value for identity the reference, for example: @JsonBackReference(value="myValueForTheReference")

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'process': no back reference property found from type `java.util.List<com.app.model.AnsweredQuestionnaire>`

Comment: could you please provide some reference to this, so that i can read. i mean when we have more than one reference to the same class